# Большое количество переадресаций golang

Tags: nginx, golang

Есть вот такой код на golang. По сути самый простой сервер, использующий порт 1338, который выводит ok.
Ещё ниже находится часть конфига nginx и скриншоты результата запроса к серверу.
При одном обращении происходит 509 переадресаций (509 выводов ok и такое же количество входящих запросов, которые видно в терминале).
И вот не могу понять почему же такое происходит.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

type DebugTransport struct{}

func (DebugTransport) RoundTrip(r *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    b, err := httputil.DumpRequestOut(r, false)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
    return http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(r)
}

func main() {
    target, _ := url.Parse("http://мойдомен.ру:1337")
    log.Printf("http://0.0.0.0:1338 -> %s\n", target)

    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(target)

    proxy.Transport = DebugTransport{}

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        _, _ = w.Write([]byte("ok"))
        req.Host = req.URL.Host
        proxy.ServeHTTP(w, req)
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":1338", nil))
}
```

Есть кусок конфига nginx, в котором тоже всё понятно.

```
server 
{
    listen 1337;
    server_name     мойдомен.ру;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://0.0.0.0:1338;
    }
}
```

[image: 509 ok]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, вывод в качестве текста

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вы в хендлере вашего запроса используете proxy.ServeHTTP(w, req)?

из документации https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/ :

ReverseProxy is an HTTP Handler that takes an incoming request and sends it to another server, proxying the response back to the client.

У вас идет рекурсивное проксирование запроса на текущий сервер.

Comment: Убрал ServeHTTP, помогло. Спасибо)